# Chrome Developer Tools - Where is the (index) stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, developer-tools

I was modifying a theme for a WordPress based site, the *Anew theme* to be specific. Although I changed the theme options - `style.css` file and `custom.css` file, I couldn't change the color of the links.

Then I used Chrome's Developer Tools to check where my rules were overridden. The overriding rule was on an `(index)` file, with parenthesis. With no relevant information on the internet, I decided to take a look at it later.

After some hours, all my changes were committed and now it shows the new color. But I am still curious about this `(index)` file. Is it a script-added rule?

Comment: It may be the HTML file itself. You should be able to click the word `(index)` though and it should take you to the source view. Can you show a screen shot?

Comment: if you open Chrome Developers Tool , on the right side where you look at the style tab , you should also see the "computed" tab next to it.   open that and find your style and expand it to see where its overwritten.

Comment: Was `(index)` not a link? Usually in developer tools I can click and it brings me to the style.

Comment: When I click on the (index) link it shows me an empty file. But both answers helped me to understand. Chose the second because of the PHP  and JS reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably CSS embedded in the HTML (`style` tags in the `head`), either as part of the markup or added dynamically via JS (or possibly by PHP when the page is rendered).

Need more info to give any answer more specific than that.

Comment: Within WordPress some theme devs create a css.php file to output these styles in the head or template. These will show as within "index" also.

Answer (score 7):

When you see index it means the page you're on. The CSS is directly embedded into the page instead of in a separate file.